# Jquery complete callback for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

yes so as the title denotes,  I can't get the #logo-side opacity change to complete even though the rest of the code does I think it needs a complete added to the function but not sure where... Can someone help?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");
        $("#logo").animate({
            left: '-115px',
            top: '-60%'
        }, 'slow',
        function () {
            $("#logo-side").animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 5000);
        });

        $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 2000);
});
```

**HTML CODE ON REQUEST**

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/mthc/logo-main.png" height="130px" width="420px"></a></div>
        <div id="textbit" class="text">
            <p>
                <span class="word one"></span>
                <span class="word one">Music</span>
                <span class="word two">Expression</span>
                <span class="word three">People</span>
                <span class="word four">Potential</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loader-section"></div>
</div>


 <div id="logo-side" class="tile-area-title"><img src="images/mthc/logo-main2.png" height="130px" width="380px"></div>
```

Comment: Wut? There's no interval. And why would he increase it to 5000?

Comment: its my way of saying that i want logo-side to be faded in AFTER the 2 seconds

Comment: The animation for opacity just stops if you do anything on the page so i want to make sure it completes , simple

Comment: As i can see, it works as expected. Can you replicate your issue on jsFiddle with all relevant CSS too

Comment: So I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5xorgs1/), what's wrong with it?

Comment: thanks for the fiddle but it basically doesn't fade in completely so if i do something else with other navigation it doesn't finish , is there a way to ensure it compeltes its 100% opacity ?

Comment: @havingagoatit Can describe , demonstrate _"do something else with other navigation it doesn't finish"_ ?

Comment: no you misunderstand, it should work independently but as soon as you do ANYTHING on the page any click or something else happens the animation stops dead ! i just want the animation to finish !!!

Comment: @havingagoatit So block UI until animation finishes, see e.g: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ If still not what you are looking for, please, again, provide jsFiddle replicating your issue

Comment: @havingagoatit What is _"ANYTHING"_ ? `html` not included at Question ?

Comment: @A.Wolff Just noticed `<a href="index.html">` following `<div id="logo">` that does not appear to have closing `</a>` tag ?

Comment: aything could be a click that executes some more jquery .. that has nothing to do with the fact that the animation opacity is NOT completing and should do so irrespective of any other click ... i could replicate it on jsfiddle , but that would mean putting best part of an entire website on there and in the spirit of SO "get to the point" i have isolated the problem wihtout all the stuff that frankly could be any other executed code , it stops it dead

Comment: @havingagoatit Check provided jsFiddle, you are wrong  https://jsfiddle.net/n5xorgs1/2

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok. Still appear not all `html` ,`js` included at Question ?

Comment: @havingagoatit I'm glad you have spotted from where comes from your issue. I hope you'll find a solution then, sincerely ;)

Answer (score 3):

you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");

        $("#logo").animate({
             left: '-115px',
             top: '-60%'
           },
           {
             easing: 'slow',
             complete: function(){
               $("#logo-side").animate({
                 opacity: 1
               }, 5000);
             },
             duration: 2000
           }
        });

      $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Not tested.

Comment: No OP is already using the complete callback

Comment: this is pretty much exactly what I am trying to do although this code doesn't work... how do get the complete function to work ?

Comment: @havingagoatit This code has the exact same behaviour as yours except regarding options

Comment: mine doesn't use complete: and although this code above doesn't work the centiment is bang on correct !

Comment: @havingagoatit It is: `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`  You are passing `complete` function, not using `properties` object, but that's a shorthand for the same thing

Comment: $("#logo-side").animate({
           opacity: 1
           }, 2000),complete;
       });

Comment: i don''t know if that syntax would work , i have probably got it wrong

Comment: @havingagoatit It must be `$("#logo-side").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000, complete});` where `complete` is a referenced method to call on complete. Maybe use it to initialize your menu plugin but if there is some errors regarding this menu plugin, fix it instead. I said that because and don't really see any reason for initializing a plugin to stop any animation except if there some unhandled script error

Comment: thanks , that didn't work stopped all code

Comment: im debugging at the moment but there dont seem to be any unhandled script errors

Comment: @havingagoatit All the problem comes from we don't know what plugin you are using which makes your animation stop working. I'd suggest you to repost a new question at least including this plugin link and better describing your issue (not having for futur readers to read all comments, i meant)

Answer (score 0):

Appear that `#logo-side` `opacity` not set to `0` at `css` ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");
        $("#logo").animate({
          left: '-115px',
          top: '-60%'
        },'slow',
        function(){
           $("#logo-side").animate({
           opacity: 1
           }, 5000, function() {
             // load, initialize `multipushmenu` , or other `plugin` here,
             // to insure animation to opacity ` completed;
             // e.g.; 
             // $.getScript("/path/to/plugin/plugin.js")
           });
       });

       $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
#logo-side {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.html">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/420/130/technics" height="130px" width="420px"></a></div>
        <div id="textbit" class="text">
            <p>
                <span class="word one"></span>
                <span class="word one">Music</span>
                <span class="word two">Expression</span>
                <span class="word three">People</span>
                <span class="word four">Potential</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loader-section"></div>
</div>


 <div id="logo-side" class="tile-area-title"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/130/nature" height="130px" width="380px"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79337/discussion-on-answer-by-guest271314-jquery-complete-callback-for-animation).